# How to Change Meld Dark Theme to Light Theme?

Tags: meld

I installed Meld on Linux Mint 21 and it's in dark theme (dark background). It's a pain to do text comparison. Previously on Linux Mint 20, it's in light theme (light background). How do I change that?